# Синхронная прокрутка трех Memo

Tags: delphi

Как сделать синхронную прокрутку **трех memo**. То есть кручу **Scrollbars** и информация **в трех Memo** синхронно прокручивается.

Comment: у мемо нет какого-нить метода  `scrollTo` что ли?

Comment: @teran, Это в свойствах или это отдельная процедура ?

Comment: Речь идет **только** о вертикальной прокрутке?

Comment: @Dima, Да речь идет о вертикальной прокрутке..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ответ обновлен!**
*Упрощен код метода `Synchronize`; добавлен тип `TSyncType`.*

Это реализовать весьма несложно. Как мне показалось, наилучшим решением будет создать новый компонент (наследуясь от уже существующего - `TMemo`) и немного его улучшить.
Такой подход требует определенных трудозатрат:

1. Создание юнита для компонента.
2. Создание `*.dcr`-файла для компонента (в нем будет его иконка для
   палитры компонентов в IDE).
3. Собственно, инсталляция компонента в IDE.

С другой стороны, Вы получаете на выходе "полуфабрикат", который можно безболезненно модифицировать, распространять и не бояться, что <s>какой-то костыль</s> важный код потеряется по дороге. Тем не менее, в дальнейшем будет приведен только код, касающийся компонента. Создание пакета и его инсталляция - за рамками данного вопроса.

Вся работа базируется на перехвате сообщения `WM_HSCROLL/WM_VSCROLL`. Мы узнаём как именно пользователь выполнил прокрутку данных (за ползунок или кнопками управления полосой прокрутки) и вызываем кастомное событие типа `TNotifyEvent`. В режиме design-time необходимо выполнить настройку этого события, используя публичную процедуру новоиспеченного компонента `Synchronize` для синхронизации прокрутки *основного* компонента и *подчиненных* (определяются пользователем).

Впрочем, хватит вступления, перейдем непосредственно к коду.

*Объявление класса:*

```
  // Тип прокрутки (горизонтальный, вертикальный)      
  TSyncType = (stHorz, stVert);

  TMemoEx = class(TMemo)
  private
    FOnScrollHorz: TNotifyEvent;
    FOnScrollVert: TNotifyEvent;
    FCurrentWord: Word;

  protected
    procedure WMHSCROLL(var Message: TMessage); message WM_HSCROLL;
    procedure WMVSCROLL(var Message: TMessage); message WM_VSCROLL;
    procedure WMCOMMAND(var Message: TWMCOMMAND); message CN_COMMAND;
    function DoMouseWheel(Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer; 
                          MousePos: TPoint): Boolean; override;
    procedure KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); override;

  public
    procedure Synchronize(AMemo: TMemo; ASyncType: TSyncType);

  published
    property OnScrollHorz : TNotifyEvent read FOnScrollHorz write FOnScrollHorz;
    property OnScrollVert : TNotifyEvent read FOnScrollVert write FOnScrollVert;
  end;
```

*Реализация класса:*

```
procedure TMemoEx.WMHSCROLL(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Inherited;

  FCurrentWord := LOWORD(Message.WParam);
  if Assigned(FOnScrollHorz) then
    FOnScrollHorz(Self);
end;

procedure TMemoEx.WMVSCROLL(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Inherited;

  FCurrentWord := LOWORD(Message.WParam);
  if Assigned(FOnScrollVert) then
    FOnScrollVert(Self);
end;

procedure TMemoEx.CNCOMMAND(var Message: TWMCOMMAND);
begin
  Inherited;

  if Message.NotifyCode = EN_HSCROLL then
    begin
      if Assigned(FOnScrollHorz) then
        FOnScrollHorz(Self);
    end
  else
  if Message.NotifyCode = EN_VSCROLL then
    begin
      if Assigned(FOnScrollVert) then
        FOnScrollVert(Self);
    end;
end;

function TMemoEx.DoMouseWheel(Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer; 
                              MousePos: TPoint): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Inherited DoMouseWheel(Shift, WheelDelta, MousePos);

  if HandleAllocated then
    begin
      if WheelDelta < 0 then
        FCurrentWord := SB_LINEDOWN
      else
        FCurrentWord := SB_LINEUP;
    end;
end;

procedure TMemoEx.KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  Inherited KeyDown(Key, Shift);

  if Key = VK_HOME then
    FCurrentWord := SB_TOP
  else
  if Key = VK_END then
    FCurrentWord := SB_BOTTOM
  else
  if (Key = VK_DOWN) or (Key = VK_RIGHT) then
    FCurrentWord := SB_LINEDOWN
  else
  if (Key = VK_UP) or (Key = VK_LEFT) then
    FCurrentWord := SB_LINEUP;
end;

procedure TMemoEx.Synchronize(AMemo: TMemo; ASyncType: TSyncType);
var
  ScrollInfo: TScrollInfo;
  LongWParam: DWord;
  Msg: DWord;
  Bar: Integer;
begin
  if FCurrentWord = SB_ENDSCROLL then
    Exit;

  if HandleAllocated and Assigned(AMemo) and AMemo.HandleAllocated then
    begin
      if ASyncType = stHorz then
        begin
          Msg := WM_HSCROLL;
          Bar := SB_HORZ;
        end
      else
        begin
          Msg := WM_VSCROLL;
          Bar := SB_VERT;
        end;

      if (FCurrentWord = SB_THUMBPOSITION) or (FCurrentWord = SB_THUMBTRACK) then
        begin
          ScrollInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(ScrollInfo);
          ScrollInfo.fMask := SIF_ALL;
          GetScrollInfo(Handle, Bar, ScrollInfo);
          LongWParam := MakeWParam(FCurrentWord, ScrollInfo.nPos);
        end
      else
        LongWParam := MakeWParam(FCurrentWord, 0);

      SendMessage(AMemo.Handle, Msg, LongWParam, 0);
    end;
end;
```

Полезная информация:

1. [WM_HSCROLL message](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/wm-hscroll)
2. [WM_VSCROLL message](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/wm-vscroll)
3. [MAKEWPARAM macro](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-makewparam)
4. [EN_HSCROLL notification code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bb761680)
5. [EN_VSCROLL notification code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bb761689)
6. [Тип события TNotifyEvent](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TNotifyEvent.html)